# Error integrating Gitlab - Maven - Jfrog artivactory

Tags: maven, gitlab, artifactory

Using instructions provided here https://jfrog.com/blog/gitlab-and-artifactory-on-your-mark-get-set-build/,

- copied https://github.com/JFrog/project-examples/tree/master/gitlabci-example/gitlabci-maven-artifactory to my new project
- created generic local repo in JFROG
- set all needed variables (ARTIFACTORY_PASS, ARTIFACTORY_URL,
  ARTIFACTORY_USER, MAVEN_REPO_KEY
- CI starts working with error:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 in artifactory-release (http://192.168.196.20:8082/artifactory/test0-maven-libs-release-local) -> [Help 1]
```

It's clearly trying to find plugins in the local repo (192.168.....) instead of downloading it from inet

Question is:
What I'm doing wrong and how to make it download plugins from maven repo?
It's an official project example after all, and it's not working...

All files are cloned from GitHub JFROG repo without modification

[repo config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpEi1.png)

[CI/CD variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RttQ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Re-creating repositories in jfrog (2 local) +  adding 1 remote with url https/jcenter.bintray.com partially solved the problem.
Download started and now it failing with API incompatibility error

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) on project gitlab-demo: 
Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war failed: 
Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4' 
due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null
```